# Wifi Connections on ubuntu 16.04 LTS not available as an option

Tags: 16.04, networking

First some clarification of the problem might be needed:
I am running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS on a Dell Latitude E6220 with a windows 7 dual boot.
The machine turns on with no problems, but once logged on
there is no option in settings to configure wireless connections,
nor does the machine connect automatically to my access point
as it would usually.
The output of rfkill:

```
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: dell-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
4: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

would indicate that Ubuntu recognizes there is a wireless card installed,
however ifconfig:

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 84:8f:69:f0:a9:2b  
          inet addr:10.156.204.69  Bcast:10.156.207.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc2d:79c9:4832:5f54/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11059 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6824 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:12929276 (12.9 MB)  TX bytes:682773 (682.7 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:e1c00000-e1c20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:552 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:81751 (81.7 KB)  TX bytes:81751 (81.7 KB)
```

contradicts this, as does:

```
sudo lshw -C network
```

both indicating that there is no wireless card installed (which there is).
Attempting to turn on the card as I have seen suggested elsewhere using ifconfig
with:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

gives the following error:

```
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
```

Fiddling with aeroplane mode and the physical switch on the machine also has no effect.
I am at a loss to suggest what may have caused this as the previous session to the
one where the issue occurred I made no changes to any relevant settings or installed
or removed any networking related packages, although I know that it can't be a physical issue with the card because windows works fine.

solution:
having read [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers) and having followed the instructions to reinstall the device driver for my wireless card, wifi connection shows up as an option, and after reboot and disconnecting ethernet, the problem disappears.